# captureVisibleTab of non-visible tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to take a screenshot of non-visible tab with chrome extension API?

`chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` takes only the selected tab on a specific window.

I could programmatically switch to the needed tab, take a screenshot and switch back, but since it's all async, there's a flicker while it happens.

Comment: While it is async there are callbacks that let you run commands in order.

Comment: @serg, I can, but if I focus on that tab that I want to capture, capture it and re-focus on the previous tab, I can see the process happening. It's async and it means that there's a space between call and callback.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the page to a new window and move the window outside the screen then take a screenshot. Then the user will not notice that you have opened a new window because it is outside the screen.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: That's an interesting brilliant idea! I'll try that, thanks! Meanwhile, I solved it by taking a screenshot whenever the tab is opened. But that definitely sounds better.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I open a new window with `focused: false`, it's still in the foreground, so there's still a flicker if I change focus back to the original one. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88841